# Using a variable in an Azure Data Factory in the body of an API call

Tags: azure-data-factory

Trying to put a variable in an Azure Data Factory (ADF) API Lookup Activity.

If I put this in the body of my Lookup (variable names changed from real names):

```
{
  "Id": "Blah",
  "value": 0,
  "peak": 1000,
  "filters": {
"StatMin": "1983-09-05",
"StatMax": "2024-04-05",
"ModMin": "1969-10-15",
"ModMax": "2023-10-15"
  }
}
```

The Lookup activity runs perfectly.
However, if I try to insert a variable:

```
{
  "Id": "Blah",
  "value": 0,
  "peak": 1000,
  "filters": {
"StatMin": "1983-09-05",
"StatMax": "2024-04-05",
"ModMin": "1969-10-15",
"ModMax":  "@variables('Date')"
  }
}
```

I get a pipeline error. What am I doing wrong to format the variable entry properly?

Error below:
ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http request failed with client error, status code 400 BadRequest, please check your activity settings. If you configured a baseUrl that includes path, please make sure it ends with '/'.
Request URL: [REMOVED],Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.,Source=System,'

I have tried putting the variable in braces, quotation marks, no quotation marks, etc., and none of them have worked. I thought ADF would read the variable directly like it does in other parts of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert the variable in the string, you need to use string interpolation `@{<add dynamic content>}` .

Use the expression like below in the lookup body.

```
{
  "Id": "Blah",
  "value": 0,
  "peak": 1000,
  "filters": {
"StatMin": "1983-09-05",
"StatMax": "2024-04-05",
"ModMin": "1969-10-15",
"ModMax":  "@{variables('Date')}"
  }
}
```

[image]

You can see the variable `Date` value in the lookup activity input body.

[image]